# screen turns black after service started

Tags: android, service

My application turned black screen right after I initialize service in my activity. No error or warning message was shown. Awhile later the application is already not responding and even after the time limit the service did not update info to the server. I wanted to use the service to send user's location constantly to the server after every minute. Service is initialize in my activity. I also included the service in AndroidManifest.xml as well.

LocationService 
The code below is my structure of Service

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
    return null;
}


private String TAG = "LocationService";


@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
            boolean isUpdateResult = true;

    try{
        while(isUpdateResult){

             new CountDownTimer (60000, 1000) {



                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 }

                 public void onFinish() {
                   //Send information to server                          

                }.start();
        }
    }
    finally{

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Below is how I call the service in my main activity.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_screen);

    startService(new Intent(Web_Slider.this,
            LocationService.class));
    }
```

Any idea what causes the black screen? Did I missed out something here? 
Any comments will be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the definition of the display_screen layout?

Comment: Where is `isUpdateResult` set to false? It might be an infinite loop.

Comment: @atk I got other functions working inside main activity. I just attach the code how I initialize the startservice.

Comment: @gsingh2011 I will set that later on. Because for now I just wanted the system to constantly send out info to server. Will set that into the activity later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. Apparently if I run `new CountDownTimer (60000, 1000)` in the beginning of the loop, the screen will turned into black screen. If not mistaken is due constantly create new CountDownTimer cause it unable to function as it should. The right way to put it is take away the **While(isUpdateResult)**. The function will constantly start a count down timer because there is a .start(); after onFinish();. So there while loop is not needed.

```
         new CountDownTimer (60000, 1000) {



             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             }

             public void onFinish() {
               //Send information to server                          

            }.start();
```